# Finding all the ordered pairs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find all the distinct positive integer ordered pairs for $a+b\le100$ such that :

$$\frac{a+\frac{1}{b}}{b+\frac{1}{a}}=10$$

Comment: Simplify the LHS. :)

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $$\frac{a+\frac{1}{b}}{b+\frac{1}{a}}=\frac{a+\frac{1}{b}}{\frac{b}{a}(a+\frac{1}{b})}$$

Comment: or multiplying top and bottom by $ab (\gt 0 )$ to give $\dfrac{a(ab+1)}{b(ab+1)} = 10$

Comment: @Henry Sure. ${}{}{}{}$